# How to see and return results of a function used inside an if statement?

Tags: php

I wrote this function and I'm using it to upload an image to my local server dynamically.

I ran into the following issue, the `$image_name` is generated inside it, so when I call the `uploadImage function` I can't return the `$image_name` so that I can insert it into the database, I'm not sure how to return that variable.

```
public function uploadImage($data, $uploadLocation, $nameTag){
    if($data['size'] != 0) {
        $errors     = array();
        $maxsize    = 16777216;
        $acceptable = array(
            'image/jpeg',
            'image/jpg',
        );
        $image_extension = pathinfo($data['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        //image_name variable I'm referring to
        $image_name = uniqid($nameTag, true) . '.' . $image_extension;

        if($data['size'] >= $maxsize) {
            $errors[] = 'File too large. File must be less than 16 megabytes.';
        } else if($data['size'] == 0){
            $errors[] = 'You need to upload an image.';
        }

        if((!in_array($data['type'], $acceptable)) || (empty($data['type']))) {
            $errors[] = 'Invalid file type. Only JPG, GIF and PNG types are accepted.';
        }

        if(count($errors) === 0) {
            $moveFile = move_uploaded_file($data['tmp_name'], $uploadLocation . '/' . $image_name );

            if($moveFile){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Here I'm using the uploadImage function.

```
$uploadImage = new UploadImages();

if($uploadImage->uploadImage($data['image_data'], 'uploads/img/instructions', 'instruction_')){

    //here I'd like to return the $image_name from the function
    //I'm using PDO to insert the name in database
    $sth = $db->prepare('UPDATE instructions SET image = :image WHERE id = :id');
    $sth->bindValue(':image', //name returned from the function, PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $sth->bindValue(':id', $instructionsId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sth->execute();
}
```

I figured that in the piece of code:

```
if($moveFile){
    return true;
}
```

I could return the `$image_name` instead of true, but I'm unsure how I'd catch it to be usable since it's inside an if statement.

Any ideas how we can return that specific data, or suggestion in how to better rewrite the code to fit those needs would be great.

Comment: You do exactly what you said, return `$image_name` or create a method like `getImageName()`.

Comment: @Rasclatt It didn't come to mind to create a method to get the image name. Thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to my comment, I would maybe think about a structure similar to this:

```
class UploadImages
    {
        # Save all your persisting variables
        protected $errors = array();
        protected $image_name,
                  $success = false;
        # You may want to make this editable in the future
        protected $maxsize = 16777216;
        # You may want to add more mimes later
        protected $acceptable = array(
                      'image/jpeg',
                      'image/jpg',
                  );
        # Make a listener
        public function listen($data, $uploadLocation, $nameTag)
        {
            if(!empty($data['size'])) {
                $image_extension = pathinfo($data['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                # Store the file name
                $this->image_name = uniqid($nameTag, true) . '.' . $image_extension;
                # Use the editable variable
                if($data['size'] >= $this->maxsize) {
                    # Store error
                    $this->errors[] = 'File too large. File must be less than 16 megabytes.';
                }
                # Check editable mime
                if((!in_array($data['type'], $this->acceptable)) || (empty($data['type']))) {
                    $this->errors[] = 'Invalid file type. Only JPG, GIF and PNG types are accepted.';
                }
                # Store the success
                if(count($this->errors) === 0) {
                    $this->success = move_uploaded_file($data['tmp_name'], $uploadLocation . '/' . $this->image_name );
                }
            } else {
                $this->errors[] = 'You need to upload an image.';
            }
            # Return the object
            return $this;
        }

        public function getFileName()
        {
            return $this->image_name;
        }

        public function isUploaded()
        {
            return $this->success;
        }

        public function getErrors()
        {
            return $this->errors;
        }

        public function hasErrors()
        {
            return (!empty($this->errors));
        }
    }
# Create the class, since the listen() method returns the object, you can
# run that right off the top
$uploadImage = (new UploadImages())->listen($data['image_data'], 'uploads/img/instructions', 'instruction_');
# Check if there are errors or if the upload itself failed
if($uploadImage->hasErrors() || !$uploadImage->isUploaded()) {
    # Write the error depending on which error occurred
    echo ($uploadImage->hasErrors())? implode('<br />',$uploadImage->getErrors()) : 'Your upload failed do to an unknown error.';
}
else {
    # Fetch name on success
    $img = $uploadImage->getName();
    $sth = $db->prepare('UPDATE instructions SET image = ? WHERE id = ?');
    $sth->execute(array($img,$instructionsId));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store it in `UploadImages` field, and write a method to get it.

Answer (score 0):

You can return `$image_name` from function. In if it will be executed as `true` condition if your function return anything except `false / null or 0` value.

```
if($moveFile){
   return $image_name; //you can add file name here
}
```

upload image function

```
//Following condition become true if function return file name and not `false`
if($image_name = $uploadImage->uploadImage($data['image_data'], 'uploads/img/instructions', 'instruction_')){
     //You can use filename now
    //here I'd like to return the $image_name from the function
    //I'm using PDO to insert the name in database
    $sth = $db->prepare('UPDATE instructions SET image = :image WHERE id = :id');
    $sth->bindValue(':image', //name returned from the function, PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $sth->bindValue(':id', $instructionsId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sth->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can do this. First, you do need to return the $image_name on success instead of true. Then you can do

```
$filename = $uploadImage->uploadImage($data['image_data'], 'uploads/img/instructions', 'instruction_');
if($filename !== false){ //uploadImage returns false on error
  ...
```

or

```
if($filename = $uploadImage->uploadImage($data['image_data'], 'uploads/img/instructions', 'instruction_')){
```

In the second method, the single equal operator sets $filename to the result of the function call, and the whole statement also evaluates to the result of the function call. I prefer the first method, as it is easier to read and understand.